# ODDR2 usage found in auto-generated xilinx wrapper VHDL file

Tags: vhdl, xilinx

I'm using the TEMAC IP core to generate a 1gb ethernet MAC, and came across an interesting piece of code:

```
-- DDr logic is used for this purpose to ensure that clock routing/timing to the pin is
-- balanced as part of the clock tree
   not_rx_clk_int <= not (rx_clk_int);

  rx_clk_ddr : ODDR2
    port map (
      Q  => rx_clk,
      C0 => rx_clk_int
      C1 => not_rx_clk_int,
      CE => '1',
      D0 => '1',
      D1 => '0',
      R  => reset,
      S  => '0'
      );
```

So according to my understanding, what's happening here is that a "new" clock is being generated by two clocks that are 180 degrees out of phase by using each clock as a select line input to the mux. (See very useful diagram below taken from page 64 [in this document](http://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/user_guides/ug381.pdf)!)

[image: figure 2.11 from page 64]

When `C0 is '1'` then `Q <= D0` which gives `rx_clk <= '1'`, and if `C1 is '1'` then `Q <= D1` which gives `rx_clk <= '0'`. During reset both flipflops are reset giving `rx_clk <= '0' while reset = '1'`

---

So I have a few questions:

1. Are the two clocks (`not_rx_clk_int` and `rx_clk_int`) going to be precisely 180 degrees out of phase when generated in this way? (by this way, I mean `not_rx_clk_int <= not (rx_clk_int)`). I assume not due to delta time? What are the implications of this?
2. What is the benefit of using the ODDR2 in the first place (why isn't `rx_clk <= rx_clk_int` adequate)? (Which leads to...)
3. What does it mean for a clock to be "balanced" as part of the clock tree? (clock tree mentioned briefly on page 59 [here.](http://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/user_guides/ug382.pdf))
4. Isn't `rx_clk` being gated during reset? Isn't this bad?
5. Is this the "standard" way of using a ODDR2 and/or performing this operation? Are there better options?  (and hence, should I add this to my arsenal of useful VHDL bits and pieces? )

Feel free to suggest recommended reading and/or other resources. I don't want to blindly copy/paste this code into my project without knowing exactly what's going on here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 1) Are the two clocks (`not_rx_clk_int` and `rx_clk_int`) going to be precisely 180 degrees out of phase when generated in this way? (by this way, I mean `not_rx_clk_int <= not (rx_clk_int)`). I assume not due to delta time? What are the implications of this?

Yes, they will be pretty well exactly phased.

Delta-delays are not at issue here.  They only apply to HDL simulations, standing in place of unknown "real" delays. I would hope that Xilinx got their model correct so that both edges change in the same delta cycle!  ie. they do something like:

```
not_rx_clk <= not (rx_clk_int);
rx_clk <= rx_clk_int;
```

to match the deltas.

> 2) What is the benefit of using the ODDR2 in the first place (why isn't `rx_clk <= rx_clk_int` adequate)? (Which leads to...)

It ensures that the delay is predictable relative to the other IOs that you no doubt have synchronised with this clock.  If you just drive the clock signal out of a pin, it has to come off the clock distribution network, through some routing, and then to the pin (as there's no direct route for a clock net to get to the IO pin.  That's a delay which is unpredictable and likely to vary from one compile to another.

> 3) What does it mean for a clock to be "balanced" as part of the clock tree? (clock tree mentioned briefly on page 59 [here.][3])

As I understand it, it means that the clock tree makes sure that the clock goes the same distance (approximately) to every destination.

> 4) Isn't `rx_clk` being gated during reset? Isn't this bad?

Yes it is being turned on and off (I'd hesitate to use the word 'gated' as that means a specific thing - being fed through an AND gate - which this isn't). Only you can say if that matters - it depends on where it goes to.

> 5) Is this the "standard" way of using a ODDR2 and/or performing this operation? Are there better options?  (and hence, should I add this to my arsenal of useful VHDL bits and pieces? )

Three questions in one, sneaky :)

- Yes, it's (a) standard way of using ODDR2 (the other standard use is for actual DDR data of course).
- No, I don't know of a better way to simply get a clock out.
- Yes, add it to your arsenal.

Comment: Very nicely put. Just want to comment on "Delta-delays only apply to HDL simulations". True, but probably worth mentioning that they "stand in" for real but unknown gate or signal delays, which DO apply to synthesis and real logic. So simulation may reveal a delta cycle skew here, and a "naive" synthesis could well do the same. But by the time XST has done with it, we can be sure that inverter has gone! Now, if we were to insist on it with "keep" attributes and MAP/PAR constraints, I wonder if we would see that skew?

Comment: RE: deltas - you're quite correct, they stand in for real delays.  The main point is that the XST sim model ought to match the reality of what ends up in the FPGA - so if there is a negligible (hah - who defines that then! :) delay in silicon, the sim-model ought to have no deltas in it.

Comment: wholeheartedly agree. My concern was just that an inexperienced reader might get "delta delays aren't important" in a more global sense than "deltas aren't the issue here".

Comment: What's the advantage of using a ODDR2 instead of a BUFG? My understanding is that a BUFG would also bring the clock onto the clock tree instead of it being routed as a normal signal. The Xilinx module has an ODDR2 and a BUFG in series. What's the benefit of this? As far as I can see, the difference of the between the ODDR2 and a BUFG is the presence of the flip flop?

Comment: Ah. Understood. It's ext_clk_in -> BUFG -> ODDR2 -> clk_out.

Comment: @MartinThompson strange request I know, but would it be possible to delete and repost these comments without my full name in them? Just to remain more anonymous. Thanks!

Comment: Comment repost with more anonymity: BUFGs bring a clock onto the internal clock trees, the ODDR2 allows a clock from the internal clock tree onto an external pin. The outputs of an ODDR2 should usually go straight to the PIN driver, not to a BUFG

Answer (score 2):

Partial set of answers:

1) I'm amused by the unnecessary brackets in `not (rx_clk_int);` like a lot of Xilinx cores, it makes me wonder if it's auto-translated from Verilog or something; there's a lot of really bad VHDL in some of them. (So I'm easily amused.) Anyway...

Synthesis tools probably optimise out the separate "not" and use the falling edge of rx_clk_int, so you certainly can get 180 degree phase shift this way. (Whether it's guaranteed, or a more complex expression might fool synthesis, I can't say).

2) Straight assignment would take rx_clk_int off the clock tree, onto ordinary routing, through an output buffer and the total delay would be anybody's guess. This way you have precisely timed clocks directly in the IOB for more predictable timing.

3) FFs and IOBs right next to the clock gen don't see the clock before the ones in the far corner; balancing the clock tree is slowing up all the short paths to match the longest one. (You can see this on DIMM memory PCBs, a lot of zigzag lines on traces to lengthen them!)

4) I would expect it to be gated. Whether that's bad depends on what it's clocking. Perhaps an Ethernet expert can chip in here. Or chase the logic driving "reset" to this block; it may not be the main system reset, to fix this issue.

5) It's certainly a fairly well known trick on newer FPGAs (ones with DDR regs), and very useful for clocks in addition to their main purpose (DDR inderfaces to memory etc). Keep it handy!

Comment: As an aside, purely from a use-of-xilinx-tools point of view, is it worth working in verilog in order to avoid any problems that might arise from the auto-translation issues that you mention? I suspect that changing to verilog won't be too difficult, I just haven't really had any motivation to do so yet.

Comment: I would say no; I greatly prefer VHDL, and if it's auto-translated at least it's likely to be right. It's just curious that they use VHDL so badly, at such low level. I can only speculate why, but it might be that if they wrote good VHDL it wouldn't port easily to Verilog.